# sass doesn't import my file

Tags: html, css, sass, gulp

I'm using Gulp for SASS and can't to import my file '_sections.scss'.
Error Message:
Error: scss\main.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: _sections.scss.

List of my files in sass folder are in this form:

```
  _base.scss
  _header.scss
  _mixins.scss
  _nav.scss
  _sections.scss
```

I have imported in main.scss in this form:

```
@import "_base";
@import "_mixins";
@import "_sections";
@import "_header";
@import "_nav";
```

Gulp file:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('./scss/main.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css'))
        .pipe(browserSync.reload({ stream: true }));
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: './'
        }
    });
    gulp.watch('./scss/*.scss', ['styles']);
    gulp.watch('./**/*.html').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});

gulp.task('default', ['styles', 'serve']);
```

Answer (score 0):

you should catch errors when using the gulp-sass

so your code would look like

```
.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
```

catching the error and compiling the file again should work. 
if you are using visual studio code. I think there's a thread to this issue.

https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/1894